# Serial data is not sent on interrupt

Tags: serial, bluetooth, interrupt

I have a short program which should receive data, use this data to turn on/off an LED, and send data when a button is pressed. It is deployed on a Digispark board. The button is connected to `INT0` port (PB2). The interrupt works, but data is not send. Receiving data works fine.

What am I missing here?

```
#include <SoftSerial.h>

#define RxD 1
#define TxD 0
#define out 3
#define btn 2
#define testled 4

SoftSerial blueToothSerial(RxD, TxD); //RX, TX
volatile int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(out, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(btn, INPUT);
  pinMode(testled, OUTPUT);
  setupBlueToothConnection();
  digitalWrite(out, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(testled, HIGH);
  attachInterrupt(0, intrpt, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {    
  char newVal;
  if(blueToothSerial.available()){
    newVal = blueToothSerial.read();
    if (newVal == '1') {
      digitalWrite(out, HIGH);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(out, LOW);
    }
  }
}

void intrpt() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(btn);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    // turn LED on:
    digitalWrite(testled, HIGH);
  } else {
    // turn LED off:
    digitalWrite(testled, LOW);
    blueToothSerial.println("0");
  }
}

void setupBlueToothConnection() {
  blueToothSerial.begin(9600); 
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n"); 
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STNA=HC-05\r\n"); 
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n"); 
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n");    
  delay(2000);    
  blueToothSerial.print("bluetooth connected!\n");    
  delay(2000); 
  blueToothSerial.flush();
}
```

**EDIT**

Serial data is sent fine. The above code works. On Windows I can see the data are coming, but not on OS X.

Comment: it appears your interrupt would trigger itself, it that intended?

Comment: Which board are you using here?

Comment: @Majenko Digispark with attiny85 http://i.imgur.com/LT4szAd.png

Comment: @Dandavis it triggers itself because of lack of debouncing, but shouldn't it send data even if it's unintentionally triggered?

Comment: no, i mean you println() on the TX pin, which changes its hi/low state, triggering the interrupt. TX==0

Comment: @dandavis, ohh I see... I thought 0 represents `INT0`... Now I've tried with `attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(btn), intrpt, CHANGE)` but it cannot compile because `digitalPinToInterrupt` is not declared in the scope.

Comment: hmmm. https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=370167.0 ?

Comment: @dandavis seems 0 is INT0, which is on PB2 - https://digistump.com/board/index.php/topic,1060.msg12633.html#msg12633

Comment: Why would you use software serial on the hardware serial pins?  If you're going to use those pins, then just use Serial.  It works a lot better than any flavor of soft serial.

Answer (score 1):

If you are handling interrupts then you need to keep the code as quick and simple as possible.  I suspect that in this case calling `blueToothSerial.println` is what's causing the problem. It may well be calling an operation that an ISR can't call and so it fails and your code doesn't write the data you expect it to.

All I ever do in ISRs is set flags and then get the 'normal' code to handle changes to the flags. Personally I wouldn't do the digitalWrites within the ISR. Have two volatile variables, one for the pin state and one when sending a message is required and handle those in your `loop()`.